# How to prove this: $a^4+b^4+2 \ge 4ab$?

Tags: inequality

How to prove this: $a^4+b^4+2 \ge 4ab$?

$a$ and $b$ are reals.

Comment: I think the Ravi substitution might be helpful but I am not sure.

Comment: What's an optional scalar?

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you explain its source, include any work you have done, and explain where you are stuck so that we can write a response that is appropriate for your skill level.

Comment: @tomasz, the question is correct. $a=b=1$ is the minimum point for $f(a,b)=a^4+b^4+2-4ab$.

Comment: Note that $(a^2-b^2)^2\ge -2(ab-1)^2$

Comment: @Arashium: Wow, that was some spectacular miscalculation on my part. That's embarassing. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 7):

There's a fast way to apply the [arithmetic-geometric mean inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality):

We split up $2$ into $1+1$ and get

$$\frac{a^4+b^4+1+1}{4}\ge\sqrt[4]{a^4b^4}=ab$$

Rearranging, we are done.

Comment: Can you show me @Peter Woolfitt that what you mean at rearranging it?

Comment: @encuka Yes, I just mean multiply by $4$ on both sides and making the $1+1$ a $2$ again, so then we have $a^4+b^4+2\ge 4ab$ as desired.

Comment: That's really neat!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that:

$$(a^2+b^2)^2 = a^4 + b^4 + 2a^2b^2$$

So, then we have that: $(a^2 + b^2)^2 - 2a^2b^2 + 2 \ge 4ab$

It follows that:
$$(a^2 + b^2)^2 \ge 2a^2b^2 + 4ab +2 -4,\ (a^2 + b^2)^2 \ge 2(ab+1)^2 -2^2 = \left(\sqrt{2}(ab+1) + 2\right)\left(\sqrt{2}(ab+1) - 2\right)$$

Our inequality now becomes:

$$(a^2 + b^2)^2 \ge\left(\sqrt{2}ab+\sqrt{2} + 2\right)\left(\sqrt{2}ab+\sqrt{2} - 2\right)$$

**NOTE** This manipulation may or may not assist you in proving the inequality. I only provided it as a possible way to help you in your proof.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible method is generation of a function and calculating its minimum:

$$f(a,b)=a^4+b^4+2-4 a b$$

$$D_a f(a,b)=4 a^3-4 b = 0$$

$$ a^3=b$$

$$ f(a)=a^4+a^{12}+2-4a^4=a^{12}+2-3a^4$$

$$D_a f(a)=12a^{11}-12a^3=0$$

$$a^3 (a^8-1)=0$$

Minimum must be at one of:

$$f(0,0)=2$$
$$f(1,1)=0$$
$$f(-1,-1)=0$$

so

$$f(a,b)=a^4+b^4+2-4 a b\geq0$$

Answer (score 1):

Inequalities like this can most often be proved or simplified by using the Arithmetic-Geometric mean inequality.

First apply AM-GM in $a^4$ and $b^4$:

$$\frac{a^4+b^4}{2} \ge \sqrt{a^4b^4}$$

$$a^4+b^4 \ge 2a^2b^2$$

Now apply AM-GM in $2a^2b^2$ and $2$:

$$\frac{2a^2b^2+2}{2} \ge \sqrt{4a^2b^2}$$

$$2a^2b^2+2 \ge 4ab$$

I suppose the result is quite obvious now. This answer was, of course, posted with the assumption that $a$ and $b$ are reals.